# prevent link from open and activate fancybox slideshow with flickr badge

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have this piece of html from flickr badge:

```
<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image1">
    <a href="[setlink]">
       <img src="[imagelink].jpg" alt="A photo on Flickr" title="Road" height="75" width="75">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image2">
    <a href="[setlink]">
       <img src="[imagelink].jpg" alt="A photo on Flickr" title="Road" height="75" width="75">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image3">
    <a href="[setlink]">
       <img src="[imagelink].jpg" alt="A photo on Flickr" title="Road" height="75" width="75">
    </a>
</div>
```

Whenever I click, the [setlink] will be opened. How do I prevent the click through, and open up fancybox with a SLIDESHOW, when I click the link. Thanks.

**EDIT** (moved from comments)

I did this :

```
$(".flickr_badge_image a").fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).find('img').attr('alt');
        this.href = $(this.element).find('img').attr('src');
    }
})
```

also

```
$('.flickr_badge_image a img').fancybox();
```

and

```
$('.flickr_badge_image a').fancybox();​
```

Comment: I did this: `$(".flickr_badge_image a").fancybox({
        beforeLoad : function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).find('img').attr('alt');
        this.href = $(this.element).find('img').attr('src');
    }
  })` also `$('.flickr_badge_image a img').fancybox();` and `$('.flickr_badge_image a').fancybox();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, bear in mind that the fancybox gallery will consist of the elements in your badge ONLY, not all your photos from your photostream. To make a fancybox gallery, you need to set the same `rel` attribute to each (`<a>`) element of the gallery using the `.attr()` method like :

```
$(".flickr_badge_image a").attr("rel", "gallery")
```

**Second**, `[setlink]` doesn't have any *image* extension so you need to tell fancybox that the content are images. Force the content `type` to `image` with the API option `type: "image"`

**Third**, you can hack the correct *URL* of each target image from the `src`  attribute of the `img` tag in the thumbnail, so for instance :

```
<img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/32/102691513_68290d6cdc_t.jpg" width="75" height="100" title="a corner" alt="A photo on Flickr" >
```

**Notice** the name of the image has the *suffix* `_t` (thumbnail). If we remove the suffix `_t` then we have the big image path of the corresponding thumbnail, so from the example above

```
href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/32/102691513_68290d6cdc.jpg"
```

... is the path to the big image that we want to display in fancybox.

We could use the javascript's method `replace()` to remove the *suffix* like

```
.replace(new RegExp("_t", "i"), '');
```

Your complete code should look like (no need `preventDefault`) :

```
$(".flickr_badge_image a").attr("rel", "gallery").fancybox({
    type: "image",
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.href = $(this.element).find('img').attr('src').replace(new RegExp("_t", "i"), '');
    }
});
```

See it working in this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JEcNA/)**

**EDIT** : to set the `title` use :

```
this.title = $(this.element).find('img').attr('title');
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JEcNA/1/)**

Comment: It works as advised. I am almost speechless by now. I guess fancybox wasn't able to find the image, and then decided to open the link. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(function() {
  $(".flickr_badge_image a").click(function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      $(this).fancybox(...);
  })
});
```

`ev.preventDefault()` - prevents default browser behaviour for specified event. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Thanks, but that prevented everything. And I also needed a slideshow. not just one image in lightbox. I also tried returning false;